# unresponsive keyboard and mouse after update

Tags: updates, keyboard, mouse

I have Dell Inspiron desktop machine running Ubuntu 14.04 with dual boot.
At some moment I started having non-responsive USB keyboard and mouse on wake up after suspend on some occasions. As I'm lazy and it did not occurred often I just rebooted and continued my work.
At last I got no keyboard or mouse after reboot. Keyboard works in grub and both fail on login screen. Plugging keyboard/mouse off/on did not help.
I re-installed 14.04.02 and it worked out of box just fine until I installed all updates. Then no keyboard or mouse again.
I installed 12.04 and it worked exactly as 14.04! Fine out of box, no keyboard or mouse after installing updates.
I ended up installing 14.04, disabled all updates and it is fine so far, but I want to know what causes this problem and what specific update is at fault.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spare keyboard or mouse then login go into setting > software and updates then under the tab additional drivers what till you see drivers keep you other keyboard and mouse plugedin so it can look for those as well. If it doesn't work then you might want to reasearch you piticular mouse and keyboard and look for anything similar to your situation.